# Why storage space does not allow you to use the full size of a disk

Tags: windows, ssd, storage-spaces

I have a storage pool with 3 SSD disks. They have different sizes, the largest one has 500GB. But after I added it to the pool and extended my volume, I found about 6GB of space I could not use.

I wonder if that space is used to store metadata. But 6GB for metadata is a bit too much, isn't it?

[image]
[image]

### Usage of all physical disks

[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshots for all the disks in the pool?

Comment: Certainly 6 GiB of metadata would be on the larger side, but then it is only 0.5% of the volume size. Not that much after all! Lots of data means lots of metadata. One dubious claim I found is that every expand operation uses a few gigabytes of extra metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The problem **here** is that difference between 1.2TB and 1.1TB is more than **6G**.  It is in fact **100G**.

That is why you are unable to change the size from 1.1TB to 1.2TB.

- In other cases of differences, sometimes, the calculations are confused and are using a mixture of 1000 and 1024 for kilo.
- In other cases of differences, the storage is in blocks. Each file uses up more than its physical size (like rounding up).  So, the sum of filesizes is going to be smaller than the space they occupy.